# Circular buffer using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, circular-buffer

Is it possible to do a circular buffer using SQL?

I mean, using table myTable:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
```

Something like

```
SELECT id FROM `myTable` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5 OFFSET 3
```

would actually return

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to maintain the restriction of the limit and start ordering by the offset?  If so, something like this could perhaps work:

```
  select id
  from mytable
  order by !(id>3), id
  limit 5
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dd97/1)

I've altered the input to include a 6th record to show the limit functionality.

Comment: I am trying to maintain the restriction of the limit and start at the offset, but if I am at the end of the table and I don't have the limit of element, I want to fill the rest from the beginning.

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard -- I think this does that.  Look I my edited reply -- looks much simpler now after thinking about it...